# How can I populate a dropdown list excluding any one option from another dropdown list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have three drop down lists labelled as Subject Choice 1, Subject Choice 2 and Subject Choice 3. Only the first Subject list is populated upon the web page loading. How can I populate the second list on changing the first and the third list on changing the second list? Also another requirement is that each list to be populated should be mutually exclusive.

Lets have an example: initially the Second list and Third List are void. Say The first list contains:

1. Bengali
2. English
3. Mathematics
4. Physics
5. Chemistry

Now the user selects say 3) Mathematics, then the second list will be

1. Bengali
2. English
3. Physics
4. Chemistry

This time if the user selects say 2), then the third list will be

1. Bengali
2. Physics
3. Chemistry

I am looking for the whole thing to be done using pure JavaScript or jQuery if absolutely needed, but no database interaction.

```
                    <!-- javascript code for dynamic dropmenu For Hons 2 Subject -->
                    function AjaxFunctionHonsSub2(hons_sub_id2)
                    {

                    var httpxml;
                    try
                      {
                      // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                      httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      }
                    catch (e)
                      {
                      // Internet Explorer
                              try
                                        {
                                     httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                                        }
                                catch (e)
                                        {
                                    try
                                {
                                httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                 }
                                    catch (e)
                                {
                                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                                return false;
                                }
                                }
                      }
                    function stateck() 
                        {
                        if(httpxml.readyState==4)
                          {

                    var myarray=eval(httpxml.responseText);

                    // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements

                    for(j=document.applicationform.hons_pref_sub3.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
                    {
                    document.applicationform.hons_pref_sub3.remove(j);
                    }

                    // add option for subject 3
                    var index=0;
                    var optn2 = document.createElement("OPTION");
                    optn2.value = '19';
                    optn2.text = '------SELECT------';
                    document.applicationform.hons_pref_sub3.options.add(optn2);
                    for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(index<myarray.length){
                            var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                            optn.value = myarray[index];
                            optn.text = myarray[index+1];
                            document.applicationform.hons_pref_sub3.options.add(optn);
                            index+=2;
                            }
                    } 

                          }
                        }
                    var url="fetch_hons_subject.php";
                    url=url+"?hons_sub_id="+hons_sub_id2;
                    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
                    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
                    httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
                    httpxml.send(null);
                      }
                    <!--# end javascript code for dynamic dropmenu ======================================================================-->
```

Comment: you're unlikely to get an answer on this without trying some code out yourself. see how far you can get yourself and then post any code you're working on if you get stuck. if you don't know where to start, then try a javascript beginners tutorial. look at jquery too. tuts.com do great free tutorials.

Comment: @dewd7. To be honest, I am not stuck if I use AJAX call and maintain a planned database . However, I am giving here the code which is working ok, but my requirement is to do it without AJAX call. Please revisit my post.

Comment: its unlikely, (although it happens), that someone is going to convert code for you. i suspect you are a db/ server specalist, looking for a client specialist to do the client side work for you. this is not that kind of site. you have to make an attempt to do what you want to do and ask for help on specific points if you get stuck.

Comment: It's good that you've shown your AJAX version, but if you want to do it without that, that's quite a few changes. As @dewd says, can you give it a go first? Maybe rendering a JavaScript array in PHP, and accessing values in there, will be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following code. It is not a very elegant approach but it works fine. I have implemented it for the second dropdown, you can implement similarly for the third dropdown as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeDD2()
{   
    var ddTemp = document.getElementById('mydropdown');
    var dd2Temp = document.getElementById('mydropdown2');
    var ddSelectedIndex = ddTemp.selectedIndex;
    if(ddSelectedIndex==0)
    {
        alert("Please select valid input");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(var i=1;i<ddTemp.length;i++)
        {
            if(i!=ddSelectedIndex)
            {
                var opt = ddTemp[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt.text;
                el.value = opt.value;
                dd2Temp.appendChild(el);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="mydropdown" name = "mydropdown" onChange="changeDD2()">
    <option>None</option>
    <option>Maths</option>
    <option>Bio</option>
    <option>Physics</option>
    <option>Chemistry</option>
</select>
<select id="mydropdown2" name = "mydropdown2">
</select>
<select id="mydropdown3" name = "mydropdown3">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

A lot of things could be generically/dynamically driven here avoiding the use of the hard code.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Sameer. You showed me the way. Thanks to you all.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. If you got a solution through it, please upvote the answer..